# A tinkered PC resets its nameserver (resolv.conf) on each boot

Tags: networking, internet

The Ubuntu 11.10 PC resets resolv.conf on each boot, only with a comment remaining.

How do I fix this by setting the persistent storage?

It was tinkered by somebody else and I (and him!) cant trace his actions. The graphical connection manager also refuses to work thanks to the tinkering.

Content of interfaces file:

```
root@technovia-3:~/dev/spectrum/spectrum# cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When theres a manual entry in the /etc/network/interfaces, Your graphical network interface wont work.

Either you remove the entries in interfaces file in relate to the interface(eth0,eth1) you are working on. Then restart networking using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`, after which you can use the graphical interface

Or edit interfaces file to include nameservers, like `dns-nameservers <ip>` and restart networking.

Comment: "theres a manual entry" what should I remove? The files?

Comment: post the entries in interfaces file here.

Comment: Posted the file

Comment: @aitchnyu that means loopback interface, thats wont be a issue.Then you should be able to manage the interface graphically.
If you dont get a icon, then try `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`

Or else add entry in interfaces http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/